# You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out in Queueable apex

Tags: apex, cpq, queueable-apex, cpq-api

I am getting the following error

`You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`

while executing  the below code

```
global class AmendContract_Queueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    global void execute(System.QueueableContext qc) {
        String quoteJSON =
            SBQQ.ServiceRouter.load('SBQQ.ContractManipulationAPI.ContractAmender',
                contractId, null);
        system.debug('quoteJSON' + quoteJSON);
        QuoteModel q = (QuoteModel) JSON.deserialize(quoteJSON, QuoteModel.class);
        system.debug('q RecID ' + q.record.Id);
        //step 2 - loop thru my quote & change the quantity
        for (QuoteLineModel qlm: q.lineItems) {
            qlm.record.SBQQ__Quantity__c = 1;
        }
        //step 3 - save changes to the quote
        String savedquote = SBQQ.ServiceRouter.save('SBQQ.QuoteAPI.QuoteSaver',
            JSON.serialize(q));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear at all from this snippet where exactly the error is, but at least one of these methods `SBQQ.ServiceRouter.load` or `SBQQ.ServiceRouter.save` does a callout, but before the callout is made, something is saved in (or deleted from) the database. To pinpoint this exactly look at the debug log for `DML_BEGIN` to find the exact location of DML calls.

Comment: Hope you have checked with this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328873&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1) i.e. standard documentation..!!